# Maven resource folder

Tags: java, maven

Hy,
I want to get the resource folder (ex: C:\Users\Raul\workspace\Serial\src\test\resources) in a Maven project but every time I run this java code:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("").getPath());
```

it returns me this path: C:/Users/Raul/workspace/Serial/target/test-classes/

The last time I used Maven, worked that way without any changes from me.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Resources aren't (necessarily) file system entries. Don't use them as such.

Comment: the program should create, modify and delete the files from there.

Comment: It really shouldn't. Don't mix your development environment with your runtime environment.

Comment: i used the same methode in another project and it worked fine. here the github link: https://github.com/Raul-Vasi/EbookConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a typical setup, Maven copies the resources to the `target/classes` (or `target/test-classes`) directory. Also, the `target/classes` (or `target/test-classes`) directory is added to the classpath.

If you have a file `src/test/resources/foo.txt`, then you would access the file using `getResource("/foo.txt")`.

Generally speaking, you would not want your code to refer to source folders to access resources. Resources might be put in multiple locations and it is pretty common to "filter" the resources (replace tokens with build property values). In the filtering case, you absolutely do not want the processed resource files to be in the source directory.

Comment: thx. and if I have to write and read files from inside a jar file (non visible for normal user), how do I make this now?

Comment: @RaulVasi I have not tried it recently, but I believe that any file in any jar in the classpath is available using `getResource()`. If bar.jar contains a file at the top level called foo.txt, then I believe you can say `getResource("/foo.txt") and get the file, whether it is in a jar or is directly on the classpath.